# BasicHttpParams - adding a date format(ClassCastException)

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

The relevant code snippet:

```
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
Object dateFormats = "E, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
List<Object> dateFormatList = new ArrayList<Object>();

dateFormatList.add(dateFormats);

params.setParameter(CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS, dateFormatList);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/sample_user.json");

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
```

I've tried to cast the List with String, an array, using Arrays.asList on a String Array, everything I could think of.  But every single time I get a ClassCastException like the one below.  I've went through the source code and at the line where the exception occurs, the BestMatchSpecFactory uses getParameter() to retrieve the param set in CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS(which should be my List<>) and saving it into a Collection.

Here's the code from BestMatchSpecFactory.java in org.apache.http.impl.cookie at line 49:

```
Collection<?> param = (Collection<?>) params.getParameter(CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS);
```

ArrayList implements List which implements Collection, so what exactly is the problem with casting here?

```
02-28 10:09:29.117: W/System.err(1222): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
02-28 10:09:29.137: W/System.err(1222):     at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BestMatchSpecFactory.newInstance(BestMatchSpecFactory.java:49)
02-28 10:09:29.137: W/System.err(1222):     at org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpecRegistry.getCookieSpec(CookieSpecRegistry.java:113)
02-28 10:09:29.137: W/System.err(1222):     at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:147)
02-28 10:09:29.147: W/System.err(1222):     at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:290)
02-28 10:09:29.147: W/System.err(1222):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:160)
02-28 10:09:29.167: W/System.err(1222):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:401)
02-28 10:09:29.167: W/System.err(1222):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-28 10:09:29.181: W/System.err(1222):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-28 10:09:29.181: W/System.err(1222):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-28 10:09:29.181: W/System.err(1222):     at com.duderlabs.candr.MainActivity.readTwitterFeed(MainActivity.java:80)
02-28 10:09:29.181: W/System.err(1222):     at com.duderlabs.candr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
02-28 10:09:29.189: W/System.err(1222):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-28 10:09:29.217: W/System.err(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-28 10:09:29.217: W/System.err(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-28 10:09:29.217: W/System.err(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-28 10:09:29.217: W/System.err(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-28 10:09:29.238: W/System.err(1222):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 10:09:29.238: W/System.err(1222):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 10:09:29.258: W/System.err(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-28 10:09:29.258: W/System.err(1222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 10:09:29.258: W/System.err(1222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-28 10:09:29.258: W/System.err(1222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-28 10:09:29.258: W/System.err(1222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-28 10:09:29.258: W/System.err(1222):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE**

I've updated the code based on an answer below:

```
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
String dateFormat = "E, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
Collection<String> dateFormatList = new ArrayList<String>();

dateFormatList.add(dateFormat);

params.setParameter(CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS, dateFormatList);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/sample_user.json");

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
```

But still getting the same exception.

Comment: u r missing some lines of code in which you have issues - please modify the post

Comment: The stack trace leads back to the last line of the top snippet, where it is executing the request.  The stack trace ends at the middle code snippet, where BestMatchSpecFactory attempts to cast the param into a Collection.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Spec](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html), this is how you should register `CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS` (though your code is correct):

```
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
String dateFormats = "E, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
java.util.Collection<String> dateFormatList = new ArrayList<String>();

dateFormatList.add(dateFormats);

params.setParameter(CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS, dateFormatList);
```

For debugging, I will also try and see if

```
client.getParams().setParameter(CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS, dateFormatList);
```

Causes the `ClassCastException`. If not, then there's something wrong with your `params`.

Comment: Then paste the full code where the exception is occurring. I'm assuming somewhere else the issue might be occurring.

Comment: Hmmm...There really is nothing else I can paste in.  The first line of the snippet above is the beginning of a method(literally, right under the signature), and the last line is where the stack trace starts from.  The stack trace ends up at the line I pasted from BestMatchSpecFactory.java.  There is no missing lines in between except the calls it makes in other packages like AbstractHttpClient, BasicHttpProcessor, etc.  Do I need to find those methods as well and paste them?

Answer (score 0):

actually, it should be

```
client.getParams().setParameter(CookieSpecPNames.DATE_PATTERNS, new String[] { ... });
```